# Batch file: read registry hidden and showsuperhidden

Tags: batch-file, registry, key, hidden

I'm writing a batch file and I need to read the values Hidden and Showsuperhidden in the registry, and put them into variables i guess. I have this so far:

```
reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced/vHidden
```

I'm not sure how all this works but I'm reading up on it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parsing reg query result is a pain.
Here's how you can do it :

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v "Hidden" ^| findstr Hidden') do set hiddenvalue=%%b
```